# Dealing with covariant derivatives (xCoba)

Tags: xact

I do not understand why the output of the two commands:

```
metric[-c, -d] (CD[d][RicciScalar[CD][]]) (CD[c][RicciScalar[CD][]]) // Simplify,

(CD[-c][RicciScalar[CD][]]) (CD[c][RicciScalar[CD][]]) // Simplify,
```

is different. The first one outputs a scalar function, as expected, whereas the second gives an expression

[image]

that I do not know how to contract.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal version of your code that reproduces the error when run on a "clean" kernel?  It may help in tracking down the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a product of a Basis[-c, {1, B}], for some basis B, and a CTensor[comps, {B}][c] object.

You can use ContractBasis to force the contraction of a Basis[...] object with anything.

Or you can use FromBasisExpand to convert a Basis[...] object into a  CTensor object, and the two CTensor objects will then be automatically contracted.

Comment: Oh wow, this is the guy that made the package :o I'm wondering if you've answered my questions in the past :D